# JSF calls actions on CDI bean when page is loaded

Tags: jsf-2, cdi

In a JSF file `addLink.xhtml` I use a CDI bean `LinkAdapter`. When the JSF file is processed, every method in the `LinkAdapter` is called several times, although most of them aren't even referenced anywhere in the whole project by now.

The `LinkAdapter` is `@Named` and `@SessionScoped`. But I think that this is not relevant, since it seems to happen with every other bean in any other JSF file.

Can anyone tell me the reason of this behavior?

I use JBoss AS 7.0.2, prettyfaces (JSF2) 3.3.2 and Weld 1.0.0.Final

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times

Comment: It does not only affect getters, e.g. the methods `editLink()` and `saveLink()` are also called. These are methods that invoke business logic and interact with the DAOs. There are also no properties or named beans that have the same name. EDIT: the `saveLink()` method is referenced in the JSF file. And if I change the method `editLink()` to `modifyLink()` the renamed method is not called anymore.

Comment: how about posting the code for the mentioned page and bean, it would be easier for someone to help that way